# Return max value for cells with same value in other cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the example:

| Reference | Value | Max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 200 |
| 2 | 300 | 500 |
| 1 | 100 | 200 |
| 2 | 500 | 500 |

I need a formula for the **Max** column, so it returns the max value from column **Value** for the same **Reference**. Tried with MAXIFS, but no success.

Comment: Look into MAXIFS

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Formula for column C

```
=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways. Try-

```
=LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$5=A2,$B$2:$B$5,0),1) 'Will work on earlier version with Array entry.
=MAX(FILTER($B$2:$B$5,$A$2:$A$5=A2))
=MAXIFS($B$2:$B$5,$A$2:$A$5,A2)
```

[image]